# Azure Active Directory Group - Change Group Policy via API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

We have a permission system which is based on Azure AD Security Groups. All of the azure access can be controlled by assigning employees to the corresponding team (group). This can be done by our project managers who gets assigned owner of their teams.

We automated the creation of the groups and the access reviews as well as the syncronisation to the distribution groups ([as mail-enabled security groups cannot be created via graph api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-groups?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) we need to  create distribution groups and sync them).

This works really well - the managers are responsible themselfes for their teams. Until someone sets the group policy to "This group is open to join for all users":

[Azure Security Group Policy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJdeH.png)

From then on our "self controlled system" is breached as everyone can join themself. We know that the one how changes the policy is also the owner who can manage the group anyway. But we dont want them to be able to change this policy (even by mistake).

The Problem: afaik it is not possible to disable or disallow the group policy selection when creating the group (or on AD level). Well, thats ok we thought. We have a webhook when the group changes (and it gets fired when changing the policy) anyway, so we just change it back.

But i cannot find any way or any api to do this. Is this missing? There isnt any field on the graph api [entity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#group-entity). And no [cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/groups-settings-v2-cmdlets#update-groups) either.

Has anyone figured out a way to change the group policy of an azure security group programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs it is possible to turn off this functionality at the domain level:

> "Make a group available for user self-service Sign in to the Azure AD
>   admin center with an account that's a global admin for the directory.
>   Select Users and groups, and then select Group settings. Set
>   Self-service group management enabled to Yes. Set Users can create
>   security groups or Users can create Office 365 groups to Yes. When
>   these settings are enabled, all users in your directory are allowed to
>   create new security groups and add members to these groups. These new
>   groups would also show up in the Access Panel for all other users. If
>   the policy setting on the group allows it, other users can create
>   requests to join these groups. **When these settings are disabled, users
>   can't create groups and can't change existing groups for which they
>   are an owner**. **However, they can still manage the memberships of those
>   groups and approve requests from other users to join their groups**."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/groups-self-service-management

Comment: We have all this settings turned off. These settings only mean that users can create and manage the whole group them self. That we definitely don't want to have.